# How to get a property in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I need to make an update method in my application. But I'm not able to filter the specific id of the task to put as a parameter of the request. If I use filter/map it returns the two indices of the array. But through my click, I want to filter the id that I clicked. How can I do this?

```
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import { useMutation } from 'react-query'
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import { useForm } from '../../hooks/useForm'
import { useTasks } from '../../hooks/useTasks'
import { api } from '../../services/api'
import { queryClient } from '../../services/queryClient'
import { modules } from '../../utils/modules'
import { ButtonContainer, CancelButton, SaveButton } from './styles'

type UpdateNoteModalProps = {
  isOpen: boolean
  onRequestClose: () => void
}

type UpdateNoteData = {
  id: string
  form?: { [key: string]: string | number }
}

export const UpdateNoteModal = ({
  isOpen,
  onRequestClose
}: UpdateNoteModalProps) => {
  const { data } = useTasks()

  const { form, handleInputChange } = useForm({
    initialState: {
      description: ''
    }
  })

  const id = data?.filter((note: any) => note._id)
  // .filter((note: any) => note.id === note.id)

  // const id = findId.find((note: any) => note.id === note.id)

  console.log({ id })

  const updateNote = useMutation(
    async ({ id, form }: UpdateNoteData) => {
      const response = await api.put(`/task/${id}`, form)

      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

      if (token) {
        api.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token
      }

      return response.data
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('task')
        onRequestClose()
        toast.success(' Sua nota foi atualizada com sucesso!', {
          position: 'top-center',
          autoClose: 5000
        })
      },
      onError: () => {
        toast.error(' Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente mais tarde!', {
          position: 'top-center',
          autoClose: 5000
        })
      }
    }
  )

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    // event.preventDefault()
    await updateNote.mutateAsync({ id, form })
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={onRequestClose}
      className="react-modal-content"
      overlayClassName="react-modal-overlay"
    >
      <h2>Editar</h2>
      <ReactQuill
        modules={modules}
        theme="snow"
        className="toolbar"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      {/* <input
        type="text"
        name="description"
        value={form.description}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      /> */}

      <ButtonContainer>
        <div onClick={onRequestClose}>
          <CancelButton>Cancelar</CancelButton>
        </div>

        <div>
          <SaveButton onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Salvar</SaveButton>
        </div>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like:
`const index = data.map(x => x.id).indexOf(x === id)`

And then you can use that index to get the data piece you want e.g. `const foundItem = data[index]`

Comment: It doesn't work, it returns undefined

Comment: does your index actually return anything when you print it?